# Elasticsearch - Skip indexing document with empty or null value

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Is there a way in a mapping for me to declare if a certain value is null, skip the document?

example document to skip indexing:

```
PUT /employees/managers/1
{
    "name": "",
    "age": 24
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a data validation constraint. 
If you mapping your document field "**name**" with ***notnull*** constraint, the document is not indexing if "**name**" is null.
Below an example of json to map the entity:

```
{ "employees": {
 "mappings": {
  "managers": {
    "properties": {
    (...)
  },
  "_meta": {
    "constraints" : {
      "name":{
        "notnull":true
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

See document: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/implementing-data-validation-in-elasticsearch/ for further use case and explanations.

Comment: Note that this is **not supported** by Elasticsearch out of the box. The linked article only explains how to implement a plugin for validating constraints via custom `_meta` data associated with the document, but this alone won't do what the question is asking.